# "Good" Ethernet cable, no connection between 2 switches

Tags: networking, ethernet, connection, switch

I'm trying to set up home networking using a cable concealed in the wall (with two wallplates on both ends), connecting two switches together and I just cannot get them to connect. In case it matters, on one end it is [TL-SG105](https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/unmanaged-switch/tl-sg105/); on the other I've tried several - [GS105NA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0000BVYT3), [TL-SF1005D](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/5-port-switch/tl-sf1005d/), [TE100-S5](https://www.trendnet.com/products/product-detail?prod=355_TE100-S5)) 
 - neither would talk. Occasionally the LED on both sides would flicker but it would never go solid.

I've tested the cable with [two](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009ZXYI1U) different [testers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DQH4XPW) but neither would find any problem (one walks each wire in order and I've verified that the order is correct on both sides; the other just reports that the cable is OK).

In case it might matter, the contractor who set up the cable did a pretty s^%$^tty job, crossing two wires. I've found the crossed wires and reconnected them in the right order, then checked using both testers to verify connectivity.

Is there something I'm missing here? My understanding is that switches will auto-sense straight cable and negotiate the connection properly. Is it possible that the cable is reported OK but still has connectivity problems?

Comment: *I've tested the cable with two different testers but neither would find any problem* Both of them can test the wiring correctness only. They do NOT test cable quality. *the LED on both sides would flicker but it would never go solid* In most cases this means that the cable is damaged (stretched, twisted, compressed) or some AC cable is posessed close to it.

Comment: Try to connect one switch and one PC, set the NIC speed 10H - 100H - 10F -100F - 10A - 100A - 1000A and detect if the speed/duplexing which allows to connect exists. If so, test these speeds for packet lost - the upper speed without it can be used. You may also try all non-standard 2-pair combinations to achieve stable 10/100 connection. But the best solution is in make new line.

Comment: Can you verify that the cable's _pairs_ are still intact? If "pair" pins aren't actually paired, a simple cable tester will still show continuity, but the signal quality will be actually trash.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and suggestions! Indeed, I suspect wiring layout might play a role. Based on what I observed the electrician wired both ends in a completely wrong order and I [mistakenly] thought that just making sure correct pins correspond to each other irrespective what wire they use would do the trick - so I just fixed the connectivity on one end without actually reconnecting the wires according to the suggested layout (which would require doing it on both ends). I'll try this in the next couple days and will report the outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the loop here - indeed, wrong ordering of the wires (even though they connected the right pins on both ends), was the culprit. Reconnecting the wires on both ends to the right pins fixed the problem. Thanks all for the hints!

Comment: That's interesting. Although undesirable and certainly out of specification, I would only have expected this to create such an obvious problem with longer Ethernet cables. Any idea how long this particular run is?

Comment: I believe, it should be about 20-25 ft - give or take...